# the little book of semaphores

Tags: multithreading, semaphore, thread-synchronization

Below is code in which each thread must wait for each other thread to complete the rendezvous part and then wait until everyone has completed the critical section.

```
/* rendezvous code */
mutex.wait()
count++;
mutex_signal()
if(count==n)
            sem.signal()
sem.wait()
sem.signal()

mutex.wait()
          count--;
mutex.signal()

if(count==0)
         sem.wait()
```

I know that two processes can reach the case where both see the same value of count (0 or n may be). Due to this two or more signals may be sent at the same time. How can there be a deadlock in the last test. I don't seem to get this.
This is a turnsile kindof semaphore arrangement and author is actually thinking it is a turnstile, but it's a semaphore and it should work without a deadlock.
Please tell me how is there a deadlock in this code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain the way I see it.

All threads but the last will come and wait at the first sem.wait(). Once the last thread arrives it will sem.signal() (because count==n) allowing one of the waiting threads(say T1) to continue. Then T1 will in turn do a sem.signal() which will allow another thread to continue. It is something like a chain reaction. Note that the last thread to pass will also do a signal which will make the Semaphore value 1.
Now if two threads come and see that the count==0 then will try to do sem.wait(). But since the semaphore value is 1, one thread will not be able to pass, causing deadlock.

Comment: But even if one thread arrives at the point count==0  , it will also wait up .Hence all the processes will wait at this point anyway . Two threads arrive or one , these threads will not be able to pass .

Comment: Are you sure? Because as I have mentioned "the last thread to pass will also do a signal which will make the Semaphore value 1". SO if one thread arrives at count==0 it will be able to do a sem.wait() and pass that point.

Answer (score 1):

The "if" statements should also be inside the critical sections designated by the "mutex" semaphore, otherwise race conditions can lead to deadlock.

I.e., the correct code is

```
/* rendezvous code */
mutex.wait()
count++;
if(count==n)
        sem.signal()
mutex.signal()

sem.wait()
sem.signal()

mutex.wait()
      count--;
if(count==0)
     sem.wait()
mutex.signal()
```